# Filter/Search a collection based on 2 attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone.js-collections

I am trying to search a collection using 2 search parameters. Currently I am only managing to search via 1 search paramater, here is my working single parameter search.

```
search: function(filterValue) {
    var filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    var matcher = new RegExp(filterValue);
    var found_models = this.filter(function(model) {
        return matcher.test(model.get('name').toLowerCase());
    });

    return found_models;
},
```

is there way to also search another attribute other than the name, I thought maybe something like this,

```
search: function(filterValue) {
        var filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
        var matcher = new RegExp(filterValue);
        var found_models = this.filter(function(model) {
            return matcher.test(model.get('name').toLowerCase());
        });
        var found_models = this.filter(function(model) {
            return matcher.test(model.get('clients').get('name').toLowerCase());
        });

        return found_models;
    },
```

but these to just overwrite any results that match the name parameter.

Comment: Is found_models an array? It looks like you need to combine the results.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in the returning of the `filter`. If you return `true` that model is added to the output. This means you can do any kind of matching within the filter function, even double matching!

So code would be something like:

```
var found_models = this.filter(function(model) {
    return matcher.test(model.get('name').toLowerCase()) && matcher.test(model.get('clients').get('name').toLowerCase());
});
```

This gives `true` && `true`, which will make `true` to your return.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [`where`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) method?

```
var friends = new Backbone.Collection([
  {name: "Athos",      job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Porthos",    job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Aramis",     job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "d'Artagnan", job: "Guard"},
]);

var musketeers = friends.where({job: "Musketeer"});

alert(musketeers.length);
```